# Error on running the pipeline in CocoaPods task

Tags: azure-devops

I've configured an pipeline for an iOS-App which use cocoa pods as follows:

```
- task: CocoaPods@0
  inputs: 
   forceRepoUpdate: false
```

on running the pipeline I getting an error:

> Invalid 'Podfile' file: cannot load such file -- cocoapods-catalyst-support

The Podfile already contains definition for 'cocoapods-catalyst-support'

```
require 'cocoapods-catalyst-support'
platform :ios, '10.3'
...
catalyst_configuration do
  # my specific configs
end
```

And I also found an solution to install the 'Bundler', configured the Gemfile as follows:

```
gem 'cocoapods'
gem 'cocoapods-catalyst-support'
```

and running 'bundle install

But still getting the previously mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

When I have had errors like this in other YAML tasks its because I need to specify a working directory or project directory. Looking at coca pods task: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/cocoapods?view=azure-devops` it seems it needs the same thing under inputs:

`workingDirectory: # Optional projectDirectory: # Optional`

Here is an Example of a Terraform YML needing a working dir:

`- task: TerraformTaskV1@0 displayName: "plan" inputs: provider: "azurerm" command: "plan" commandOptions: "-input=false" environmentServiceNameAzureRM: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }} workingDirectory: ${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}`

I think the pods task needs the same parameter. For the working dir parameter I put this: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/ClassroominthecloudTerraform`

It basically references two folder structures down in my repo. The top of your repo is the System.DefaultWorkingDirectory that's what works for me hope this helps. Sorry I haven't used the Cocoa task it is something I wish to build later on though so interested to see if the working dir works out for you.

Comment: Hi Jason, Azure can locate our Podfile, but unfortunately doesn't know about 'cocoapods-catalyst-support' pod and can't work with it. 
By commenting the 'cocoapods-catalyst-support'-lines inside the Podfile out, lets the pipeline complete the run successfully.

Comment: @AntonioK can you share your pipeline.yaml file?